# iOS 16.4, SwiftUI bottom sheet is sometimes ignoring presentationDetents

Tags: ios, swiftui, bottom-sheet

From iOS 16.4 in SwiftUI we can use the `.sheet` modifier with `.presentationDetents` to specify the height of a bottom sheet. We can further use `.presentationBackgroundInteraction` to allow interaction with the view behind the sheet.

I'm encountering a problem that looks to me like a SwiftUI bug.

You can paste this code into a playground to see the buggy behaviour in action (this is a simplified version of my actual app that has the issue).

*The bug is that sometimes when changing from one selection to another, the sheet completely ignores the `.presentationDetents` and `.presentationBackgroundInteraction` modifiers. It just shows as a full height modal without any background interaction.*

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    let choices = [nil, "One", "Two", "Three"]
    @State var selection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Choose", selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(choices, id: \.self) { choice in
                    Text(choice ?? "None")
                        .tag(choice)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .sheet(item: $selection) { choice in
            Text("Item selected: \(choice)")
                .presentationDetents([.medium])
                .presentationBackgroundInteraction(
                    .enabled(upThrough: .medium)
                )
        }
    }
}

extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { self }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView().frame(width: 320, height: 568))
```

Here are some screenshots:

| No modal | Correct modal | Buggy modal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

**Observations**

1. Hiding the sheet (by tapping 'None') before selecting another choice *never* exhibits the bug.
2. Jumping from one selection to another *sometimes* (but not always) exhibits the bug, e.g. jumping directly from 'One' to 'Two'.
3. My actual app is not using a `PickerView`, so it's not to do with that.
4. I'm assuming it's ignoring `presentationBackgroundInteraction` because it has gone way past `.medium` and up to full height.

So it seems to be an issue with a sheet's selection not passing through the nil state before changing to another selection, which to me is a perfectly valid thing to want to do (I don't want the sheet disappearing then re-appearing).

**Assuming this is an actual bug, any ideas how can I work around it?** I don't really want to write or import a third party library for something that should be working natively.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use `sheet(item:)` if you don't want the sheet disappearing and reappearing. Even if the `presentationDetents` bug is fixed, I think the intended behaviour of `sheet(item:)` is still going to be "dismiss the sheet then present another one" when the item changes.

Use `sheet(isPresented:)` instead. Show the sheet as long as the selection is not nil.

```
.sheet(isPresented: isNotNil($selection)) {
    if let selection {
        Text("Item selected: \(selection)")
            .presentationDetents([.medium])
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .medium))
    }
}
```

```
func isNotNil<T>(_ binding: Binding<T?>) -> Binding<Bool> {
    Binding {
        binding.wrappedValue != nil
    } set: { notNil in
        if !notNil {
            binding.wrappedValue = nil
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you don't mind the sheet disappearing and appearing again, you can add a separate `@State` for presneting sheet. Set that state to an intermediary `nil` value when `selection` changes.

```
@State var sheetItem: String?
```

```
.onChange(of: selection) { x in
    sheetItem = nil
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        sheetItem = x
    }
}
.sheet(item: $selection) { choice in ... }
```

Comment: `sheet(isPresented:)` was definitely the way to go, thanks @Sweeper. I've also filed a bug with Apple as I'm sure it's not the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug ... just today I also came across the same problem. The solution is to add the `.id()` modifier to let SwiftUI know the sheet you are presenting is different from the previous one, so it can assign the detents property again.

```swift
.sheet(item: $selection) { choice in
    Text("Item selected: \(choice)")
        .id(choice)
        .presentationDetents([.medium])
        .presentationBackgroundInteraction(
            .enabled(upThrough: .medium)
        )
}
```